# How to get the IP address from "docker-for-desktop" node?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, docker-for-mac

I'm trying to get the IP address of the "docker-for-desktop" node.

I'm switching from minikube to docker-for-desktop because it doesn't require VirtualBox.

[image: Screenshot of docker-for-desktop]

I created a service that exposes a NodePort. When I use minikube context, I'm able to reach the service via minikube's IP address. When I switch to docker-for-desktop context, I'm not able to reach the service because I don't know its IP address.

With minikube, I was able to do:

```
$ minikube ip
```

or even:

```
$ minikube service list
```

I'm not sure how to do that with docker-for-desktop.

I would expect to have a command that gives a docker-for-desktop IP address.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Minikube is creating a virtual machine that has its own IP, but when using Docker for Mac, you use your own laptop, so where you were using the minikube ip you can now just use `localhost`. It's just simpler.

Comment: I just checked and it works. I can access the service with `localhost:$(NODE_PORT)`.

Comment: Note that this is true on Windows as well.

Comment: Localhost works!. However, someone knows why the IP address returned by the command `kubectl get node -o wide` doesn't work?.

Answer (score 1):

on windows you can check with ipconfig

look for  IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.XX.XX

later run:
curl http://192.168.XX.XX:nodePort

note: nodePort is port configured in your service or you can get via kubectl get service #refer PORT(S) field